# Raspberry Pi libcamera-vid is zoomed

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W with RPi cam v2 (64-bit BullsEye)

The image was taken with `libcamera-jpeg -o test.jpg -t 2000 --width 640 --height 480`

The video was taken with `libcamera-vid -o test.h264 -t 2000 --width 640 --height 480`

Why is the video zoomed in?

[image: jpeg]
[image: vid]

Update: I noticed when I do use `libcamera-hello --list-cameras`
the output is:

```
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : imx219 [3280x2464] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10)
    Modes: 'SRGGB10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [206.65 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                             1640x1232 [41.85 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                             1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                             3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
           'SRGGB8' : 640x480 [206.65 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                      1640x1232 [41.85 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                      1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                      3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
```

Why is it saying `1280x960 crop` next to 640x480?

Comment: See the images here https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#sensor-modes

Comment: that has nothing to do with it, resolution is same